# Searching across multiple FHIR resources with a single request

Tags: hl7-fhir

I found a similar question (link below) but it didn't quite address my question.  I'm hoping to understand if there is a convention in FHIR for searching across multiple resources with a single request.  For instance, I want to find all patients that have a *Med Order for drug NNN* who also have an *Observation with LOINC-code XYZ*.  A request such as

[base]/Observation?subject=Patient/123&code=8480-6

gets me partway there but then I would have to execute a 2nd query to filter based on the med orders

Here is the similar question:
[Is it possible to search multiple FHIR resources with a single GET Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558356/is-it-possible-to-search-multiple-fhir-resources-with-a-single-get-request/43659708#43659708)

Comment: also posted this question on Zulip and Lloyd McKenzie pointed me to the "_has" parameter - see  http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/search.html#has.  This seems to be what I was looking for.